# HAProxy load balancer in front of Django instances

Tags: django

I'd like to have haproxy caching/redirect the /static/.+ url path of my django instances to speed up static file serving. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, HAProxy doesn't do caching. For that you want something like Squid.

As far as treating /static/ seperately, you can set up your HAProxy config to redirect any URLs matching a pattern to another backend cluster:

```
frontend my_website *:80
    mode http
    acl static url_beg /static/
    use_backend my_static_proxy if static
    default_backend my_django_server
```

Comment: Squid is great for speeding up cached static data.  Might I suggest you serve your static data on static.domain.com instead of a subdirectory.  Also, you can cache full pages in squid if your http headers are set properly in Django.  A further optimization would be to structure your urls so that fully dynamic pages are directly requested by the Django backend and don't run through squid.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try varnish instead of squid. It's much more flexible and has a much newer design, you should read
http://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/ArchitectNotes